# Show the user who made the last modification on a document in Plone

Tags: plone

I'm trying to find out who is the user who last changed a document.
Preferably, I would like to make collections based on this info...
All I can find is the Modification Date...

Using the script from [this link](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/view-an-objects-catalog-information), I do not seem to find the information on the last user in the metadata.

Is this correct( no modifying user info...), and if so, can it be done?

Comment: I am pretty sure Plone stored only creator by default, not modifier. You might need to add your own hook to save this data too with every edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @MikkoOhtamaa wrote, Plone doesn't save the last modifier on object by default. But [Plone does have version control enabled by default](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/plone-4-user-manual/managing-content/versioning-plone-v3.3) for Pages, News Items, Events and Link (by CMFEditions) and version metadata has the information of the latest modifier.

If it's OK to read the information from the version metadata and limit the feature only for version controlled content types, I think, you'd need to

1. [Register a new index](http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searching_and_indexing/indexing.html#adding-index-using-add-on-product-installer) (using `catalog.xml` in your add-on's Generic Setup -profile; you may also want to register a metadata column to get the indexed data be returned in results):

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <object name="portal_catalog" meta_type="Plone Catalog Tool">
     <index name="last_modifier" meta_type="FieldIndex">
       <indexed_attr value="last_modifier"/>
     </index>
     <column value="last_modifier"/>
   </object>
   ```
2. [Register a custom search condition to be used in Topic-collections](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/enable-collection-indices-fields-for-searching-for-custom-types) (using `portal_atct.xml` in your add-on's Generic Setup -profile) and a metadata column to get the information listed on its tabular view:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <atcttool>
     <topic_indexes>
       <index name="last_modifier"
             description="The last user, who has modified the object"
             friendlyName="Last Modifier"
             enabled="True">
         <criteria>ATCurrentAuthorCriterion</criteria>
         <criteria>ATListCriterion</criteria>
         <criteria>ATSimpleStringCriterion</criteria>
       </index>
     </topic_indexes>
     <topic_metadata>
       <metadata name="last_modifier"
                 description="The last user, who has modified the object"
                 friendlyName="Last Modifier"
                 enabled="True"/>
     </topic_metadata>
   </atcttool>
   ```
3. [Write a custom indexer](http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searching_and_indexing/indexing.html#custom-index-methods), which [looks up the last modifier](http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/content/history.html#getting-the-complete-revision-history-for-an-object) from the version metadata and indexes it:

   ```
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
   """Last modifier indexer"""

   from zope.component import getUtility

   from plone.indexer import indexer

   from Products.CMFCore.interfaces import ISiteRoot, IContentish
   from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName


   @indexer(IContentish)
   def indexLastModifier(context):
       try:
           creator = context.Creators()[0]  # fallback value
       except AttributeError:
           creator = None
       except IndexError:
           creator = None

       site = getUtility(ISiteRoot)
       rt = getToolByName(site, "portal_repository")

       if rt is None or not rt.isVersionable(context):
           # not versionable; fallback to the creator
           return creator

       history = rt.getHistoryMetadata(context)
           if not history:
           # empty history; fallback to the creator
           return creator

       if not rt.isUpToDate(context):
           # history not up-to-date; fallback to the authenticated user
           mtool = getToolByName(site, "portal_membership")
           if mtool.isAnonymousUser():
               # no authenticated user found; fallback to the creator
               return creator
           else:
               return mtool.getAuthenticatedMember().getId()

       length = history.getLength(countPurged=False)

       last = history.retrieve(length - 1)
       if not last or type(last) != dict:
           # unexpected version metadata; fallback to the creator
           return creator

       metadata = last.get("metadata")
       if not metadata or type(metadata) != dict:
           # unexpected version metadata; fallback to the creator
           return creator

       sys_metadata = metadata.get("sys_metadata")
       if not sys_metadata or type(sys_metadata) != dict:
           # unexpected version metadata; fallback to the creator
           return creator

       principal = sys_metadata.get("principal")
       if not principal or type(principal) != str:
           # unexpected version metadata; fallback to the creator
           return creator

       return principal
   ```
4. And register the indexer in your add-on's `configure.zcml`:

   ```
   <adapter name="last_modifier"
            factory=".indexers.indexLastModifier" />
   ```

Be aware, though, that because the version control mechanism is triggered by the same events as catalog indexer, we may not be sure that the metadata for the most recent version exists when we are called to index it. Above, I apply dummy heuristics that when the repository says that the version history metadata is outdated when compared to the object to be indexed, I index the username of the current user instead (and expect that user been just editing the document).

Comment: I'm thinking of trying to use the information @Yuri uses below and creating the indexes and search condition from your answer. Feasible?

Comment: @Speediro Almost. I ended up looking what the history viewlet did, with a little bit CMFEditions' interface definitions, and used its API directly. A nice surprise was that was the existing `ATCurrentAuthorCriterion`, which allowed collection to show results for the logged-in user.

Comment: great answer Asko!

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.plone.org/content/history.html#getting-the-complete-revision-history-for-an-object

has all the info you need about document history. you can also see the info clicking on "History" below the document title.

Comment: The document you link to is specific to CMF Editions, which needs to be enabled explicitely. It is not available by default. The stock Plone history viewlet (what is rendered if you click on "History") only shows workflow history, not editing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Martijn, thanks, I was reluctant to make the same comment.

Comment: @Yuri:  this was the reason I didn't accept yet. The comment did give me other valuable tips though.

Comment: Hm, I can see who edited an item in the @@historyview, and also in the doc Yuri points to it says "For instance, you can determine who the last person to modify this Plone content was". Using Plone 4.1.4.

Comment: history shows editing and does diff too. The docs says:
"Refer to the source of plone.app.layout.viewlets.content for more information about ContentHistoryView, ContentHistoryViewlet and WorkflowHistoryViewlet. Using these other class definitions, you can see that you can get just the workflow history using .workflowHistory() or just the revision history using .revisionHistory()."

Just try it before downvoting something, I've already got all the info without enabling CMFEdition, even though I needed only the workflow history that time. But you can get all the infos from the viewlet code.

Comment: @downvoter: please upvote Yuri's answer again, as it's totally correct, thx.

Comment: Though I'm not familiar enough with the road towards creating new functionality, it seems as if the necessary information is saved and retrievable. From here to an online list (read table view) where not the owner but the last editor is shown, is a few hurdles too much for me at my currect level of knowledge. A tip in that direction and I'll gladly accept the answer :-)